# Unable to install MSIX package on Windows 2016 (build 1607)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-installer, appx, msix

I have a developped a UWP Console project in Visual Studio.

Now I want to publish it by creating an App Package by Sideloading (indeed, targeted computers are not connected to internet and cannot access to the Windows Store).
Visual Studio gives me .msixbundle file, with a .cer, a .ps1 and the dependencies libraries (appx files).

I can install my package on recent computer using Power Shell and the .ps1 file, and it works fine.

But on computer running on Windows 10 Version 1607, I cannot install it. The error is that msixbundle are not supported.

I have tried with MSIX Core, it allows me to install manually the package with the command line msixmgr.exe -Unpack ....

But I cannot install dependencies libraries and my program cannot run. When I run it I have errors saying that dependencies libraries are needed.

How can I install those libraries please on Windows 10 Version 1607 ?

- Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.Debug.2.2.appx
- Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2.appx

Is there another possibility to create an installation package that works on Version 1607 ?

I have found the appx files in the Dependencies folder, but when I try to install them, I have this error message :
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Not sure, that it's correct, but [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/create-appinstallerfile-vs) says that _The app installer file is only generated when the TargetPlatformMinVersion is Windows 10, Version 1803 or greater._

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The minimum version of my project is Windows 10, version 1809

Comment: You probably need the x64 vc's from [here](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe). Then you can download latest, `*.msixbundle` package and rename it to zip, then extract it. Then find and extract the *msix* with 7zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I cannot install dependencies libraries and my program cannot run.

The problem is that you have not install dependence packages in current OS system. And you could install that dependence manually.

The  dependence package will be stored in the `Dependencies` folder where under the appx folder. Please find it and install it manually.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to install them, but I have an error message "Cannot open app package, Reason : 0x80070490 - Unable to open package". I have updated my question to display this error message. Have any idea please ?

Comment: 0x80070490 means the package was damage, please delete them and re-build the package again. For better solve this I will share the dependency [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlLBgdBasvMrgadcFziRxGgYyz5cnw?e=6NbQ5U).

Comment: Thank you for the files. I have downloaded them and execute them but unfortunately I have the same error :(

Comment: And have you enable os developer mode with setting page

Comment: No, I am trying to do so thank you. I have tried to activate it, but I have 0x80004005 error code. So I have tried to go to settings > app & features > add feature but developer mode does not appear here :( I am actually looking for solutions to solve this.

Comment: Windows Update was disabled. Once enabled, I have been able to download Windows Developer Mode and activate it without error in settings. Unfortunately I steel have the same error when running appx files :'(

Comment: Does your OS contain Windows Store app?

Comment: No, it does not have microsoft store app

Comment: It looks your os is ltsc edition, could you share more detail about your os ?

Comment: If you use windows server 2016, I'm afraid you could not install uwp package in it.

Comment: It is Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB 64bit v10.16.30.11.1. You think I cannot install my package because of that ? :(

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Do you think Windows 10 2019 LTSC will be fine ? Or I need to try with a no-LTSC os ?

Comment: We suggest you use normal os version that contain window store app and support uwp sideload.